# how to update and delete value from array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have an array $cart like

```
    array:5 [▼
  188 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => "176"
    "product_id" => "188"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "rear type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1890
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  176 => array:17 [▼
    "user_id" => ""
    "product_id" => "176"
    "qty" => "2"
    "date" => "03-05-2020"
    "product_type" => "wheel type"
    "custom_color_title" => ""
    "custom_color_price" => ""
    "bolt_title" => ""
    "bolt_price" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_title" => ""
    "hub_center_rings_price" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_title" => ""
    "wheel_spacers_price" => ""
    "tire_pressure_title" => ""
    "tire_pressure_price" => ""
    "product_price" => 1680
    "product_size" => ""
  ]
  224 => array:17 [▶]
]
```

how to update 188 position of qty value and delete 176 position ? $cart is session value stored variable and i have `$qty = $_POST['qty'];   $cartid = $_POST['cartid'];` $qty is update value and  $cartid is postion value .

Comment: $cart[188]['qty'] = {value} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for update you can use this

```
$array[188] = [
    'item_name' => 'value',
     ...
];
```

for delete you can use this

```
unset($array[176]);
```